# Laravel on Heroku - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: ajax, laravel, heroku

I would like to know how could I get this MethodNotAllowedHttpException. I've been trying to deploy my app to heroku, and I keep getting this error. I have some POST route:

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get  ('/', 'CodeController@index');

Route::get  ('/api/token/',         'CodeController@token');
Route::post ('/api/checkpassword/', 'CodeController@checkPassword');
Route::post ('/api/setpassword/',   'CodeController@setPassword');
Route::post ('/api/clearpassword/', 'CodeController@clearPassword');
Route::post ('/api/changeuri/',     'CodeController@changeUri');

Route::post ('/api/submission/', 'SubmissionController@submit');
Route::post ('/api/convert/',    'SubmissionController@convert');

Route::post ('/api/postresult/', 'CodeController@postResult');
Route::post ('/api/postdata/',   'CodeController@postData');
Route::get  ('/api/getdata/',    'CodeController@getData');

Route::get  ('/share/{uri}', 'CodeController@share');
Route::get  ('/{uri}',       'CodeController@open');
```

and in my javascript file I access it via ajax method. The following is one of my ajax method:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: '/api/checkpassword/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "uri": uri,
        "password": $('#password').val ()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data['status'] == 'success')
            window.location.reload (true);
        else {
            $('#checkpassword-alert').html (data['status']);
            $('#checkpassword-alert').show ();
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#checkpassword-alert').html (errorThrown);
        $('#checkpassword-alert').show ();
    }
});
```

everything worked fine on my local machine. It received the response properly. But when I deploy to heroku it goes to error function and it display `Method Not Allowed` in `#checkpassword-alert`.

Somehow I could make the routes to work (but still not as expected). I changed (or add) all the POST routes to GET and all the ajax method (type) to 'GET', and the error gone. But I got another error in my controller. it told me that some params ('uri') not set (I checked whether it is set in controller).

this is how I can pass the MethodNotAllowedHttpException:

```
Route::get  ('/', 'CodeController@index');

Route::get  ('/api/token/',         'CodeController@token');

// or just simply change these POST routes to GET
Route::post ('/api/checkpassword/', 'CodeController@checkPassword');
Route::post ('/api/setpassword/',   'CodeController@setPassword');
Route::post ('/api/clearpassword/', 'CodeController@clearPassword');
Route::post ('/api/changeuri/',     'CodeController@changeUri');

Route::post ('/api/submission/', 'SubmissionController@submit');
Route::post ('/api/convert/',    'SubmissionController@convert');

Route::post ('/api/postresult/', 'CodeController@postResult');
Route::post ('/api/postdata/',   'CodeController@postData');
Route::get  ('/api/getdata/',    'CodeController@getData');

Route::get  ('/share/{uri}', 'CodeController@share');
Route::get  ('/{uri}',       'CodeController@open');

Route::get ('/api/checkpassword/', 'CodeController@checkPassword');
Route::get ('/api/setpassword/',   'CodeController@setPassword');
Route::get ('/api/clearpassword/', 'CodeController@clearPassword');
Route::get ('/api/changeuri/',     'CodeController@changeUri');

Route::get ('/api/submission/', 'SubmissionController@submit');
Route::get ('/api/convert/',    'SubmissionController@convert');

Route::get ('/api/postresult/', 'CodeController@postResult');
Route::get ('/api/postdata/',   'CodeController@postData');
```

I can't figure out how come the routes didn't work when I deploy it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: How about accessing your API via cURL, eg: `curl -X POST {{YOUR_HOST}}/api/checkpassword -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'uri=xxx&password=yyy'`

Comment: try /api/checkpassword instead of /api/checkpassword/ in both your js file and web.php for POST method

Comment: @Alfa isn't it equal to ajax request?

Comment: @Aditya Singh wow, it worked! How is that possible?

Comment: actually when you are sending a get request your parameters will be attached after your trailing backslash so if your url is abc.com/ it will become abc.com/?a=2 however post doesn't have this luxury, so indirectly '/' refers to a directory rather than a file. Please check your htaccess file on the server as trailing backslashes are usually ignored. Glad I could help